# Should links in json-api responses be encoded?

Tags: rest, hyperlink, url-encoding, json-api

Should the query params in links appearing in [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org) responses be percent-encoded?

The examples from [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org) are not encoded, as in:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles",
    "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=10"
  },
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, there is also a note regarding encoding parameters in requests:

```
GET /articles?include=author&fields[articles]=title,body&fields[people]=name HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
```

> Note: The above example URI shows unencoded [ and ] characters simply for readability. In practice, these characters must be percent-encoded, per the requirements in RFC 3986.

Does this note apply only to requests? Or should responses also be percent-encoded, as in:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles",
    "next": "http://example.com/articles?page%5Boffset%5D=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/articles?page%5Boffset%5D=10"
  },
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the note about encoding URI's in your question applies only to the request, not the response

With a `json` string returned inside a **response**, the only thing required to escape is the double quote character `"`

GET **requests** (not responses) are a different ball of wax.  Anything in a GET request passed as a parameter in the URL must be URL encoded.  So if you have a parameter `url=http://some.url.com`, the url on the right of the parameter assignment needs encoding.

It's tricky  with POST and PUT requests.  Depending on the content type set in the header you may need to encode.  If your content type is `application/json`, you should not need to url encode anyting in your json string, (excluding the before mentioned `"`).

Now, if the specificed content encoding you state doesn't match what your sending (or if you didn't explicitly add one and it defaults to something), like if you send `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but send a json string, the API service may or may not accept it and who know what how it will treat the content inside as far a url decoding it.